# Run JxBrowser 5.4.2 in incognito mode

Tags: jxbrowser

I would like to run JxBrowser in incognito mode, so that no previously set cookie is used, and (additionally) no cookie gets persisted, though the latter requirement is not compulsory.

With recent versions of JxBrowser, [you can do it with `BrowserContextParams`](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000099104-creating-incognito-browser).

However, I am stuck with JxBrowser 5.4.2, and won't be able to change it in the foreseeable future.

I haven't found a way to do that with JxBrowser 5.4.2, because I can't see the class `BrowserContextParams`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incognito mode is supported [since JxBrowser 6.8](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000022734) version only. JxBrowser 5.4.2 doesn't support this functionality. The only way to get it is to update to the latest version.